# How to show Standard Facebook API buttons to Allow and Deny access in MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I want to allow user to login on my site using their facebook login, so what is the best way to achieve this on Asp.net MVC3/Razor application?

How to show Standard Facebook API buttons so once the user clicks on that the window pop-ups and from there user can do Allow and Deny access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do, but the basic is:

1. You need to create a Facebook App pointing to your site that will handle the authentication
2. That app will request the permissions you need to have on your side and make the link between your website and facebook
3. Consume all or part of the data that facebook provide's you.

Let's imagine this really basic example:

1. you create a facebook app pointing to http://mydomain.com/facebook-authentication/
2. in your mvc site you have a route pointing to `facebook-authentication` and there will have the `Login` [button from facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/), for example, a simple:

[image]

after the facebook user log in into your site with this button, you can, using the [Facebook SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) or the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) be able to retrieve the `user_id` and `email` of that user (among a ot more, depending on the permissions you have requested), you can now save that into your database, and let the user "access" your site.

---

If you are looking to a more complex solution, like Facebook membership and roles, you should look into a oauth 2 plugin or something similar.

I would strongly suggest that you take a look at the MIX 11 video from Jim Zimmerman (creator of the Facebook C# SDK) at Channel9

> [Facebook Development in .NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN06)

This will give you a nice start on getting Facebook stuff in your MVC site.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look into this series about claim based authentication:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268236/Claim-based-Authentication-and-WIF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278940/Claim-based-Authentication-and-WIF-Part-2

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290606/Claim-based-Authetication-WIF-Part-3

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great comparison of Social Authentication libraries for .NET

http://blog.marcmezzacca.com/2012/03/social-authentication-for-net-a-library-comparison/